# List Documentation Parts AWS apigateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway

Through `Terraform` I have created an `AWS apigateway` based on a `swagger` file.

I that `swagger` file I have added the specific AWS endpoints to document the API, like:

```
"x-amazon-apigateway-documentation": {
"documentationParts": [
  {
    "location": {
      "type": "API"
    },
    "properties": {
      "description": "This is the API description"
    }
  },
  {
    "location": {
      "type": "METHOD",
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/foo/{bar}"
    },
    "properties": {
      "description": "This is the method description"
    }
  }
]
}
```

Then I have published the documentation version 1.0 through `AWS console` and I am trying to fetch that documentation via HTTP as stated in :

[List Documentation Parts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-documenting-api-quick-start-with-restapi.html#api-gateway-documenting-api-quick-start-with-restapi-list-parts)

But, unfortunately, I can't. I am doing a GET to the endpoint

```
http://apigateway.eu-central1.amazonaws.com/restapis/<TheIdOfMyApiGateway>/documentation/parts
```

And it doesn't even give me a 4XX code but neither response nor HTTP code at all.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad was a typo in the region.
I was missing a dash, the correct endpoint is:

```
http://apigateway.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/restapis/<TheIdOfMyApiGateway>/documentation/parts
```

With **eu-central-1** instead of eu-central1

I check the naming of the regions in [AWS Regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)